# JAVA: Make objects from a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making this game called Rush Hour (where you move the red car).

So far I made a 2D array which reads levels from a text file. Now next up I want to transform the values from the text file to objects so I can start working with coordinates to move them.

To explain my code below a bit: First I'm making a 2D array 6x6, the users gets to choose a difficulty level and depending on what chose they make it will load one of the 4 levels.txt (beginner, intermediate, advanced or expert).

After you picked your level it will load the level in the 2D array (I'll provide a level below the code so you'd have an idea). When the level is loaded it adds a "0" to everything (It looks more user friendly in my eyes) and separates values with the | sign.

So now I think I need to make objects from the values I just read in my 2D array in order to move them (correct me if I'm wrong), I need to check if the values around the numbers match or don't match and if they match I need to combine them.

How do I proceed with this? Thanks in advance

My code so far:

```
public class Bord {
private static String[][] bordArray = new String[6][6];

public static void kiesLevel() {
    System.out.println("\nKies moeilijkheidsgraad\n1) Beginner\n2) Intermediate\n3) Advanced\n4) Expert");
    Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int keuze = keyboardScanner.nextInt();
    switch (keuze) {
        case 1:
            beginner();
            break;
        case 2:
            intermediate();
            break;
        case 3:
            advanced();
            break;
        case 4:
            expert();
            break;
        default:
            throw new NumberFormatException("Geef een geldige invoer");
    }
}

public static void beginner() {
    leesBordIn("c:/users/Glenn/desktop/beginner.txt");

}

public static void intermediate() {
    leesBordIn("d:/intermediate.txt");

}

public static void advanced() {
    leesBordIn("d:/advanced.txt");

}

public static void expert() {
    leesBordIn("d:/expert.txt");

}

private static void leesBordIn(String filename) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line = null;
        int r = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for (int c = 0; c < bordArray[r].length; c++) {
                if (line.toCharArray()[c] == '0') {
                    bordArray[r][c] = "  ";
                } else {
                    String characterstring = Character.toString(line.toCharArray()[c]);
                    if (characterstring.length() != 2) {
                        characterstring = "0" + characterstring;
                    }
                    bordArray[r][c] = characterstring;
                }
                System.out.print("|" + bordArray[r][c]);
            }
            if (r == 2) {
                System.out.println("=");
            } else {
                System.out.println("|");
            }
            r++;
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

}

Exmaple of a level:

```
220007
300807
311807
300800
400066
405550
```

Output example:

```
|02|02|  |  |  |07|
|03|  |  |08|  |07|
|03|01|01|08|  |07=
|03|  |  |08|  |  |
|04|  |  |  |06|06|
|04|  |05|05|05|  |
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not understood what do you want to do after you have created the bordArray Object, however I have seen that you could write the leesBordin method in a better way if you want (try to not write all your method as static):

```
private void leesBordIn(String filename)
{
    try
    {
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int r = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] fields = line.split("");
            for (int c = 0; c < bordArray[r].length; c++)
            {
                if (fields[c+1].equals("0"))
                {
                    bordArray[r][c] = "  ";
                } 
                else 
                {
                    bordArray[r][c] = ("0" + fields[c+1]);
                }
                System.out.print("|" + bordArray[r][c]);
            }
            if (r == 2) 
            {
               System.out.println("=");
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println("|");
            }
            r++;
        }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

One question, why do you put an "=" in the third line?

Then if you explain me better what you want to do after I will try to write some code also for that..

Comment: I'm  sorry I think I messed something up when I pasted the output from the console. It prints the = sign at the right, it indicates where the player has to move the red car (number 1 or 01) to.

What I want to do is make objects from the values I just put in bordArray with the text file.

As you can see for example theres |02|02|, I need to pair those to and make an object out of them in order to move them (I think this is the correct way)